# Solve $xy(1+xy^2)\frac {dy}{dx}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $xy(1+xy^2)\frac {dy}{dx}=1$

Tried to solve it as an exact ODE, but it didnt work.

Comment: Divide the equation by $x$. Multiply by $dx$ and integrate.

Comment: Im still going to have one $x$ left on the left hand side.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the solution though it's not a nice equation. http://bit.ly/1wXuHsu Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 5):

*Hint*: First solve $\frac{dx}{dy} = xy(1+xy^2)$ for $x(y)$ instead. To solve this, let $v(y) = 1/x(y)$. Also, don't forget to pick up both branches of the solution by noting that if $y(x)$ is a solution, so too is $-y(x)$.

*Update*: Alright, here's how to do it: Let $v(y) = 1/x(y)$. Then 
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{1}{v(y)^{2}}\frac{dv}{dy}
$$
giving
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dy} +yv(y) + y^{3} = 0
\end{align}
which has solution $v(y) = 2 -y^2 + C\exp(-y^2/2)$.
Hence 
\begin{align}
x = \frac{1}{2-y^2 + C\exp(-y^2/2)} =: f(y)
\end{align}
and your solution is $y = \pm f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @NickThompson Sorry I couldn't reply (ran out of battery) but now I understand the method I can see it's a good answer.